# JQuery validation plugin extension validating isn't working

Tags: jquery, symfony, symfony4

I'm making full form validation with jquery validation plugin, but for some reason I can't validate extensions, I tried to write the same code in jsfiddle and it worked just fine however when I do the same thing in my symfony4 project it throws error.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Here is my app.js:

```
....
const $ = require('jquery');
require('jquery-validation');
require('bootstrap');
require('bootstrap-slider');

$(function () {
    .....

    $('#new_estate').validate({
        rules: {
            "images[]": {
                required: true,
                extension: 'jpeg,jpg',
                filesize: 24368,
            },

        },
        message:{
          "images[]": "Incorrect file/image format!"
        },
    });
});
```

And here is my form:

```
            <form action="{{ path('save') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_estate" novalidate>

           ....

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="images">Images</label>
                <input type="file"  id="images" name="images[]" multiple/>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>
```

Image of the error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wnr4.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) As already stated, you need to include the additional-methods.js file.

2) For file extensions, use the extension rule. The accept rule is for mime types.

3) You have missed to ignore array.

extension: "jpg|jpeg|png|gif",

```
$('#new_estate').validate({
        rules: {
            "images[]": {
                required: true,
               extension: "jpg|jpeg",
                filesize: 24368,
            },

        },
        message:{
          "images[]": "Incorrect file/image format!"
        },
    ignore: [],
    });
```

Comment: Somehow completely forgot about the additional-methods.js file.
And didn't know about ignore array.
Everything works fine now,
Thank you!